# Delegation pattern in Obj-C - Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

So in my app I have the following situation:

**BackendCommunicatingClass -> (owned by) -> ModelClass -> (owned by) -> HomescreenViewController**

- HomescreenViewController is a delegate for ModelClass.
- ModelClass is a delegate for BackendCommunicatingClass.

Also on when the app launches for the first time, I have this:

**WelcomeViewController -> (owned by) -> HomescreenViewController**

- HomescreenViewController is delegate for WelcomeViewController.

When the user types a username and password in the WelcomeViewController, this information needs to get all the way to BackendCommunicatingClass, and then all the way back to WelcomeViewController to display error if needed. Right now I have implemented this by passing information to each class in the communication chain, until it gets to BackendCommunicatingClass. The result is a lot of duplication of protocol methods and I feel like I'm doing it wrong.

What do you think?

Comment: A valid alternative could be to use notification sent by the home view controller. Or KVO set up on the Back End controller.

Comment: What's a KVO? I still don't understand what notifications do exactly.

Comment: KVO is Key-Value Observing. See Apple's documentation on it. Notifications is a way of announcing something to everyone interested in something; it can be used as an event pattern or for two objects who otherwise don't have a connection to each other to communicate data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I understand it is not the clearest solution, but without seing the code, and the purpose of your program, this what I suggest.

- Implement Key Value Observing (KVO) in Back End view controller, observing change in the Home View Controller. As soon as Back end controller detect change in the text field, trough a dedicated variable in Home View controller, it fires all the operation it has to do.
- When back end finish, it sends a NSNotification with the result of the operation. Home view controller which you have made listening to such custom notification, react to that and display error message or other staff.

It may sounds complicated, but KVO and notification are easy to implement, and there are plenty of docs and tutorial on the net.

Comment: Sounds like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a clear 1:1 mapping of what those delegate protocols provide AND the delegate does not deal in UI stuff that nothing except the directly owning view controller should be concerned with, you could pass the delegate along to the end of the chain and set it directly as a delegate. This is what delegates are for - being able to allow an otherwise unconcerned object to communicate with another object.

That said, depending on how strict your layering policy is, you may prefer to encapsulate the information at every step by having different delegates.